# fluuter:dart type List<dynamic> is not subtype of list<Widget>

Tags: dart, flutter

I am returning products card list from product widget to parent class.I think type inference failed here but I couldn't figure out solution.

```
return Column(
  children: _products
      .map((element) => Card(
          color: Colors.pink,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(element.path),
              Text(element.text)
            ],
          )))
      .toList(),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this :

```
return Column(
  children: List<Widget>.from(_products
      .map((element) => Card(
          color: Colors.pink,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(element.path),
              Text(element.text)
            ],
          )))
      .toList()),
);
```

Comment: You should click on the tick icon on my answer to mark that your question is answered.